# How do I plot on top of an existing image with a logarithmic axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an image that is a reference graph with a log axis. I want to scatter my data on top of it, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Here is a working example in matlab:

```
close all
figure
img = imread('psi_vratio.png');
imagesc([0.103 0.99],[0.512 0.8],flipud(img));
set(gca,'ydir','normal');
ax = gca;
ax.YTick = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8];
ax.XTick = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0];
set(ax,'XScale','log');
hold on
scatter(0.3,0.7);
ylabel('v_{ratio}');
xlabel('\phi');
print('logplot_outMatlab.png','-dpng');
```

[image] and my attemps in python

```py
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imread('psi_vratio.png')
plt.imshow(im, extent=[0.103, 0.99, 0.512, .8], aspect='auto')
plt.plot(0.3,0.7, 'rx')
plt.ylabel('$\phi$')
plt.ylabel('$V_{ratio}$')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('logplot_out0.png', dpi=300)

fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imread('psi_vratio.png')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.imshow(im, extent=[0.103, 0.99, 0.512, .8], aspect='auto')
plt.plot(0.3,0.7, 'rx')
plt.ylabel('$\phi$')
plt.ylabel('$V_{ratio}$')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('logplot_out1.png', dpi=300)
```

[image]

How can I make it so it is not all stretched out?

Comment: Presumably you need two axes. One in the background which is linear and shows the image, the other in the foreground which hast the same limits than the background axes and has a log scaling.

Comment: Original image [here](https://imgur.com/a/YnXJgKA)

Comment: You want `aspect='equal'` so the image doesn't stretch and then you need to size your logarithmic axes to be the same size as the image's axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested already in the comments, the best way to achieve the result you want is to use two separate axes and keep the original aspect ratio:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
im = plt.imread('psi_vratio.png')

#set first axes
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.imshow(im,  aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')

#create second axes
newax = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon=False)
newax.set_xlim((0.103, 0.99))
newax.set_ylim((0.512, .8))
newax.set_xlabel('$\phi$')
newax.set_ylabel('$V_{ratio}$')
newax.set_xscale('log')
#Change formatting of xticks
newax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
#plot point
newax.plot(0.3,0.7, 'rx')
```

this is result I got:[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.