# plot over an image Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a scatter graphic over an image. The problem is that the image is in logarithmic scale, so I need to change the scale of the scatter to a determined one. But when I do that, the image changes aswell, when I don't want it to change.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


table = pd.read_csv('Coef_Data.csv', sep = ',', header = 0)
img = plt.imread("img.png")

plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(table['Fcoef'], table['Vcoef'], zorder=1)

plt.imshow(img,zorder=0)
plt.imshow(img, extent=[0, 1e6, 0, 1e6])

plt.ylabel('Vcoef')
plt.xlabel('Fcoef')
```

Plot with the image over the graphic with the scale in a wrong way

[image]

The real scale is logarithmic (from 10^0 to 10^6)

when I try this, the image turns into a scribble:

```
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

Just trying to change the scale of the plot without changing the image.
Thanks

Comment: Use two different axes. One for the log scale scatters, the other for the image. See: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Thanks! I am trying but it seems like it is not working with an image in the second axe

Comment: Please include a full minimal example, with some data and an image so anyone can copy/paste into their editor and run your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I plot on top of an existing image with a logarithmic axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455029/how-do-i-plot-on-top-of-an-existing-image-with-a-logarithmic-axis)