Log scale on Image
I am trying to impose log-log scale on an image.  Is there a way of doing this without distorting the image.enter image description here
I have written the following code in Jupyter Lab.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread

im = imread("Excavability-1.jpg")
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = (0.1, 30, 0.02, 6)
aspect = (im.shape[0] / im.shape[1]) * (xmax - xmin)/(ymax-ymin)
plt.imshow(im, zorder=0, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], aspect=aspect)
plt.xlabel(r"Point Load Index, $Is_(50)$ (MPa)", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(r"Discontinuity (Fracture) Spacing Index, $I_f$ (m)",fontsize=12)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])


Got the answer on this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455029/how-do-i-plot-on-top-of-an-existing-image-with-a-logarithmic-axis
